# Generic class method using SQLite-Net

Tags: c#, generics, sqlite-net, generic-type-parameters

I am trying to write a generic method to get the data from tables.

I am using sqlite-net ORM.

My methods compile well for delete:

```
public bool DeleteItem<T>(T NewItem)
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnection());
    var result = conn.Delete<T>(NewItem);

    //...
}
```

And

```
public void CreateTable<T>()
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnection());
    conn.CreateTable<T>();
    conn.Close();
}
```

But if I try to get Table data as list, I get a compile error at conn.Table:

> T Must be a non-Abstract Type ....

Here is my code that does not want to compile:

```
public List<T> GetAllItems<T>(string SelTable)
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(GetConnection());
    List<T> MyItems = conn.Table<T>().ToList();
    conn.Close();
    return MyItems;
}
```

Comment: what is the question for comunity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of Table in SQLiteConnection is

```cs
public TableQuery<T> Table<T>() where T : new();
```

So you have to add type constraints:

```cs
public bool DeleteItem<T>(T NewItem) where T : new()  // not required, but useful
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("xx");
    var result = conn.Delete<T>(NewItem);
    return true;
}
public void CreateTable<T>() where T : new()          // not required, but useful
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("xx");
    conn.CreateTable<T>();
    conn.Close();
}
public List<T> GetAllItems<T>(string SelTable) where T : new()
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("xx");
    List<T> MyItems = conn.Table<T>().ToList();
    conn.Close();
    return MyItems;
}
```